# How to partially specialize a template function for a specific template with int paramater

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I can't find another question which seems to answer this.

I have a template defined as follows:

```
template <int N> class classA;
```

//the body of class A is irrelevant for this problem really.

now I have a second class template:

```
template<typename T> class classX
{
 public:
  static const unsigned number;
}
```

with a default implementation:

```
template<typename T> classX<T>::number = sizeof(T);
```

I however want to have a "specialization" for classX if used with classA.
But for all/any template parameters N.
How to I do that?

thank you for your reply :)

Edited: Corrected syntax errors :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use:

```
template <int N> class classX<classA<N>>
{
   // Add the details of the specialization
};
```

BTW, your posted code has syntax errors.

```
template <int N> classA;
```

should be:

```
template <int N> class classA;
      // Missing ^^^^
```

and

```
template<typename T> classX { ...
```

should be

```
template<typename T> class classX { ...
          // Missing ^^^^
```

See the [link posted by @TonyD](http://ideone.com/QWiHX3) in the comments for a working example program.

Comment: @TonyD, thanks. Nice of you to post a link to the working code.